# PHP Pass by reference

Tags: php

I am calling this function which is modifying an array by reference:

```
function addWord(&$words, $wordIndex, $word)
{
 $words[$wordIndex] = $word;
}
```

At the function call,

```
addWord(&$words, $wordsIndex, $word);
```

($words is used only during the function call)

doesn't work. How do I make this or a similar functionality work? I want the addWord to be a separate function.

Comment: how does it not work? can you give us an error message or warning

Comment: Have you tried to `echo` or `var_dump` your results to see if they are correct?

Comment: 2 Questions.  1: Is $words defined before sending it to addWord() and what's it defined as?  2: What version of PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call your function without the reference operator:

```
 $words = array();
 addWord($words, $wordsIndex, $word);
```

Comment: Yep.. This works.. I was busy solving a simple typo in addition to this. "$words = array();" is what i was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass an ampersand in the function call; only in the function declaration.

Comment: Sorry.. I was trying out a bit.. Both didn't work actually. I get no error from php.